# How to keep truecrypt from making a .truecrypt folder (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, security, truecrypt

So I extracted the tar that the installer gave me and it all works except whenever I run truecrypt it puts a .truecrypt folder in my home witch I do not want to happen.

So how do i stop it?

Comment: IIRC, that folder is used as the mount point for the volume (via fuse/gvfs). as such, you can avoid creating it by using the command line to mount your volumes, and specifying a mount point of your choice in the command.